# Working with numeric calculations in form controls using ASP.NET web forms

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been practicing with asp.net web forms and controls and have now become a bit stuck on the best way to work with numeric data in user input forms for instance a simple example would be a input field called 'length' and one called width the user clicks a button and the result of L * W is calculated and display.

I have tested converting strings to int using Convert.ToInt32(strvalue2); and out-putting the results to the Console ok.

But when i try and convert them and output them to a form control using something like this:

```
        string strvaluel = length.Text;
        string strvalueW = width.Text;


            int numValuel = Convert.ToInt32(strvaluel);
            int numValueW = Convert.ToInt32(strvalueW);
            outputbox.Text   = numValuel * numValueW;  (error cannot explicitly convert    type 'int' to 'string'
```

I'm very new to asp.net so any help would be appreciated

Comment: On a side note, you should use `int.TryParse()` to convert a string to an integer when the string is user supplied, so that you can gracefully handle the case where they enter a non-integer value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Convert it to a string:

```
outputbox.Text = (numValuel * numValueW).ToString();
```

If you want more control over formatting (commas, etc.) use a format string:

```
outputbox.Text = string.Format("{0:N}",numValuel * numValueW);
```

See the [documentation on format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) for more details

Comment: @D Stanley so does the .ToString(); convert the int's back to strings after the calculation ? many thanks

Comment: @Ledgemoneky The result of the calculation is converted, not the arguments.  It's the equivalent of `int i = numValuel * numValueW;  outputbox.Text = i.ToString();`.  The original values are unchanged, if that's what you're asking.